# Find out how many times an argument is true or false multiple conditions R

Tags: r

I would like to get how many times the "Value" is higher for "County" (e.g. county 1) when "County" is FALSE. Here is my data. "County" is always a duplicate since it has both TRUE and FALSE.

```
data <- data.frame( "County" = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5), "Value" = c(10,20,7,15,40,32,43,13,12,16), "ID" = c("FALSE", "TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE", "TRUE","FALSE", "TRUE","FALSE","TRUE"))
```

I have tried to add a new column, but I think that's the wrong way to do it. I just want to know how many times County 1 (when it is False) has a higher value than county 1 (when it is TRUE).

The background about all this is that I would like to know if, when a county is false, will this give me a higher variance (in this case, a higher value) than when the county is true.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Can you elaborate your last sentence `whether the value is higher than TRUE for each "County"`, and maybe add your desired output.

Comment: Please elaborate your question. I don't understand what your objective is.

Comment: I have now updated my post! Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this perhaps:

```
data %>% arrange( ID ) %>% group_by(County) %>% summarize( FalseHigher = diff(Value) <= 0 )
```

You could change the name from FalseHigher to Difference if you like.

Comment: Note, you will have to guarantee elsewhere that there are only two rows for each County, and both TRUE and FALSE present.

Comment: Perfect!! That was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this `data.table` option could help

```
> setDT(data)[, .SD[Value[ID == "FALSE"] == max(Value)], County]
   County Value    ID
1:      3    40 FALSE
2:      3    32  TRUE
3:      4    43 FALSE
4:      4    13  TRUE
```

or

```
> setDT(data)[, NewCol := +(Value[ID == "FALSE"] == max(Value)), County][]
    County Value    ID NewCol
 1:      1    10 FALSE      0
 2:      1    20  TRUE      0
 3:      2     7 FALSE      0
 4:      2    15  TRUE      0
 5:      3    40 FALSE      1
 6:      3    32  TRUE      1
 7:      4    43 FALSE      1
 8:      4    13  TRUE      1
 9:      5    12 FALSE      0
10:      5    16  TRUE      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(County) %>% 
  filter(Value[!as.logical(ID)] == max(Value))
```